# StreamReader object keeps disappearing

Tags: c#, .net-core, nullreferenceexception, streamreader

I'm trying to build a simple twitter HttpClient and MySQL application using `.Net Core 3.1`, but I'm seeing an issue where result object becomes null before I'm done handling it. What should be the correct way to handle this?

Sample code:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{

    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);

    var requestUri = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream";
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer <token>");
    var stream = httpClient.GetStreamAsync(requestUri).Result;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        //while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        while (reader.Peek() >= 0) 
        {
            //We are ready to read the stream
            var ResultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tweet>(reader.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(ResultObject);
            if (ResultObject != null) // <== ResultObject disappears after this :: NullReferenceException
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ResultObject);
                string sQuery = $"INSERT INTO MySQLTable (tweet_id,text) VALUES ({ResultObject.data.id},\"{ResultObject.data.text}\");";
                Client.NonQuery(sQuery);
                Console.WriteLine(Client.Query("SELECT * FROM MySQLTable;"));
            };
        }
    }
}
public class Tweet
{
    public TweetData data;
}
public class TweetData
{
    public string id;
    public string text;
}
```

(This issue did not appear in `.Net 5.0`)

Comment: try add `await` to `httpClient.GetStreamAsync(requestUri)` and making the method asynchronous https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: Why are you reading the response line by line and deserializing each separately? JSON is not a line-based format.

Comment: @madreflection Twitter "search/stream" endpoint seems to consist of strings ending in a linebreak, unless I'm wrong. (This is purely based on the .net 5.0 results working flawlessly with exact same code)

Comment: @AndrewE Wouldn't adding await just make the program hang for eternity since we're receiving an endless stream?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in `string sQuery`.
I was trying to `.Select()` on a null member. Works perfectly fine when there is validation present for null members.